# Azure DevOps Terraform - error with azurerm_policy_assignment - "unable to parse Remediation Scope ID: ID is empty"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We have a release pipeline using the Terraform 0.12.3 series of tasks to create a VM, part of which involves creating a policy for automatically tagging the resources. Here's the relevant Terraform code that's giving an error:

```
# Assign tagging policy
resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "tag_policy" {
  count                = length(var.tagNames)
  name                 = "Apply${var.tagNames[count.index]}Tag"
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.rsg.id
  policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/2a0e14a6-b0a6-4fab-991a-187a4f81c498"
  description          = "Assign policy for Tag '${var.tagNames[count.index]}' Value '${var.tagValues[count.index]}'"
  display_name         = "Apply${var.tagNames[count.index]}Tag"

  parameters           = <<PARAMETERS
{
    "tagName": {
      "value": "${var.tagNames[count.index]}"
    },
    "tagValue": {
      "value": "${var.tagValues[count.index]}"
    }
}
PARAMETERS
}
```

(the "count" parts of the code are due to having 3 Tags to apply, which are defined in variables.tf)

The error we receive is:

```
2020-04-17T15:40:29.5769619Z Error: cannot parse "policy_definition_id" as a Policy Definition ID: unable to parse Policy Definition ID "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/2a0e14a6-b0a6-4fab-991a-187a4f81c498": unable to parse Remediation Scope ID: ID is empty
2020-04-17T15:40:29.5771388Z 
2020-04-17T15:40:29.5771960Z   on main.tf line 62, in resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "tag_policy":
2020-04-17T15:40:29.5772430Z   62: resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "tag_policy" {
```

I've double checked the policy definition ID is correct:

Name: Append a tag and its value to resources

Definition ID: /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/2a0e14a6-b0a6-4fab-991a-187a4f81c498

The guide at Hashicorp for the azurerm_policy_assignment makes no mention of requiring a Remediation Scope ID, or setting a flag to ignore it.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if there are any updates.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I think the introduction for the property [`policy_definition_id`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/policy_assignment.html#argument-reference) of the resource `azurerm_policy_assignment` misleading you in the wrong way. You can see it quote the `azurerm_policy_definition.example.id` for the property, but when you output that id, you would know that it's the resource Id of the policy definition, not the Id you provided. So the `policy_definition_id` looks like this:

```
/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefiniti
ons/my-policy-definition
```